# why my command not work when I write it in shell script?

Tags: shell, sh

The command I want to execute is:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/cjl --string='hello world'
```

when I run it in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
OPTIONS="--prefix=/home/cjl --string='hello world'"
./configure $OPTIONS
```

What is actually being done is

```
$ ./myscript.sh
+ OPTIONS='--prefix=/home/cjl --string='\''hello world'\'''
+ ./configure --prefix=/home/cjl '--string='\''hello' 'world'\'''
```

Then I modify the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
./configure --prefix=/home/cjl --string='hello world'
```

run it

```
$ ./myscript.sh
+ ./configure --prefix=/home/cjl '--string=hello world'
```

Why can't I do what I want to do?

I want and I write this in script: ./configure --prefix=/home/cjl --string='hello world'

but actually execute             : ./configure --prefix=/home/cjl '--string=hello world'

Comment: BashFAQ/050: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Aside from the correct remark by John Kugelman, consider moving from sh to (for instance) zsh, where you have arrays. A more natural way would be to define `OPTIONS` as an array, where each array element corresponds to one parameter of `configure`.

Comment: It would perhaps help to first understand why `./configure --prefix=/home/cjl --string='hello world'` and `./configure --prefix=/home/cjl --str'ing=hello world'` and `./configure --prefix=/home/cjl "--string=hello world"` all do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first script doesn't work because a shell doesn't evaluate the content of `OPTIONS` like it does when you type it directly into the command. It just pastes the contents of the variable as is, including all special characters. It does not evaluate them.

(It is easier to understand a shell if you think of most of operations as string manipulations.)

You can force a shell to reevaluate a command after building it, by using the built-in [`eval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash).

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -x
OPTIONS="--prefix=/home/cjl --string='hello world'"
eval ./configure $OPTIONS
```

(Be careful when using `eval` with user-provided strings. That may allow someone to execute an arbitrary command.)

---

Your second approach is actually correct.
In a shell, strings `--string='hello world'`, `'--string=hello world'` and even `--string=hello\ world` have the same meaning. They are just different ways to tell the shell to not split the argument at a white space character.
(`''` ignores all special characters inside it and `\` ignores the following special character.)

In each case, the value passed to the program will be "--string=hello world".